# GPSDictionary returning nil with no exif location data in metadata of uiimage

Tags: ios, objective-c

The following screenshot shows what is displayed when printing out the metadata and next to it is the exact same image which has been exported to my mac so I can view all the data from the picture (note: neither have been modified so they're exact same).
[image]

The code which I am using to get the location data is as follows:

```
    UIImage *image = (UIImage*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData *data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation( image, 0.9f );
    // EXIF DATA
    CGImageSourceRef mySourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)data, NULL);

    if (mySourceRef != NULL)
    {
        NSDictionary *myMetadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(mySourceRef, 0, NULL);
        NSDictionary *GPSDictionary = [myMetadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];
        NSLog( @"%@", myMetadata );
        //        NSLog([GPSDictionary valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude]);
        //        NSLog([GPSDictionary valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude]);

        NSLog( @"%@", [GPSDictionary valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude]);
        NSLog( @"%@", [GPSDictionary valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude]);

    }
```

Edit: For clarification the application has permission to use camera roll and the camera etc. Also tested on other iPhone devices to make sure not just an iPhone X problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out the issue was because I was trying to the GPS Data from a temporary picture which was basically a duplicated jpeg representation of the asset. The way around this is by getting the EXIF data from the **Original** asset by doing the following:

```objc
    NSURL *assetURL = (NSURL*)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL];
    NSData *originalData = (NSData*) [self retrieveAssetDataPhotosFramework:assetURL];    
    CGImageSourceRef mySourceRef = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)originalData, NULL);

    if (mySourceRef != NULL)
    {
        NSDictionary *myMetadata = (__bridge NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(mySourceRef,0,NULL);
        NSDictionary *GPSDictionary = [myMetadata objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];
        NSLog( @"%@", myMetadata );
        NSLog( @"%@", [GPSDictionary valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude]);
        NSLog( @"%@", [GPSDictionary valueForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude]);

    }
```

To get Asset URL I used a method found on here (cant find link to post now)

```objc
- (NSData *)retrieveAssetDataPhotosFramework:(NSURL *)urlMedia  {

    __block NSData *iData = nil;

    PHFetchResult *result = [PHAsset fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs:@[urlMedia] options:nil];
    PHAsset *asset = [result firstObject];

    PHImageManager *imageManager = [PHImageManager defaultManager];
    PHImageRequestOptions *options = [[PHImageRequestOptions alloc]init];
    options.synchronous = YES;
    options.version = PHImageRequestOptionsVersionCurrent;

    @autoreleasepool {
        [imageManager requestImageDataForAsset:asset options:options resultHandler:^(NSData *imageData, NSString *dataUTI, UIImageOrientation orientation, NSDictionary *info) {
            iData = [imageData copy];
            NSLog(@"requestImageDataForAsset returned info(%@)", info);
        }];
    }

    assert(iData.length != 0);
    return iData;
}
```